# Function to find a string within text file (Python)

Tags: python, text-files

I'm trying to write a function where the input string is searched for within a text file (the text file contains a list of english words, all in lowercase).
The input string may be inputted as all lowercase, uppercase or with the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase.

So far I've got this, but it's not exactly working and I'm not sure what to do.

```
def is_english_word( string ):
    with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject:

        if string in fileObject.read():
            return(True)

        newstring = string

        if newstring[0].isupper() == True:
            newstring == string.lower()

        if newstring in fileObject.read():
            return(True)
```

Comment: The first fileObject.read() reads all the file content, so the second call reads nothing.

Comment: @kantal how do you make it read one line at a time

Comment: for s in  fileObject:

Comment: Maybe I've misread your question, but why not simply doing `def is_english_word(string): with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject: if string.lower() in fileObject.read(): return True`? So justs lowering input string to be consistent to the text.

Comment: @colidyre because if the input string has an uppercase letter in the middle of string whilst the rest of the letters are lowercase, the return value should be false. Doing what you described above would simply return it true and not take into account the cases of the letters

Comment: Hm, that differs from your text: *The input string may be inputted as all lowercase, uppercase or with the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase*. If you want to also include that possibilities, simply doing `string.lower()` is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an indent issue: the `with` statement needs to be one indent inside `def`:

```
def is_english_word( string ):
    with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject:

        if string.istitle() or string.isupper():
           return string.lower() in fileObject.read()
        else:
           return string in fileObject.read()
```

there is no need to check for all of the possible cases of the input string, just make it all lowercase and check for that.

Comment: you forgot braces in the second `lower`

Comment: There's a condition where all the possible cases do need to be checked. As a word where one of the middle letters are uppercase (e.g 'pytHon') is meant to return false; but making it all lowercase will always return True

Comment: try it out now, i changed it

Comment: @vencaslac the error that was occurring is now fixed but when the whole string is uppercase, it returns false

Comment: changed again, all you have to do is change that one condiiton around a little

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def is_english_word(string):
    with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject:
        text = fileObject.read()
        return string in text or (string[0].lower() + string[1:]) in text
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.
However, it also returns True for when one of the middle letters in the word is uppercase, where it shouldn't. Eg 'pyThon' should return false but it returns True

Comment: I understand what you tried doing by checking if the first letter is uppercase, but when it is, the function returns False for some reason

Comment: What about strings of length 1?

Comment: It's ok with string of length 1

Comment: Ah sure, "x"[1:] will return the empty string and that's ok. But the accepted answer is better, imho. You have to look a second time with a manipulated string in the whole text file if given string does not match search criterion. But you already know that all is lowercased, so better doing string manipulation first and then search only one time in the text file.